# AJAX getResponseHeader('Link') returns Null in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am running into an issue where xhr.getResponseHeader('Link') returns null in IE. However, it works fine in FF, Safari, and Chrome. The IE dev console shows all the headers in the console as pictured below:
[image: IE Dev tools - Response Header Details]

xhr.getResponseHeader('Link') returns a null value. xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() returns only 3 values:
[image: Output from getAllResponseHeaders()]

Here is a snippet of my AJAX request:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': token
  },
  cache: false,
  method: "GET"
}
}).done(function(data, status, xhr) {
var link = xhr.getHeaderResponse('Link');
console.log(link)
console.log(xhr.getAllHeaderResponses());

});

});
```

Is there another method of accessing the header information that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you setting `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` on the server? It should be a comma separated list.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say IE does not support `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` being listed in multiple headers, which is why the `TrackingID` listed in the first one is available, and not the header listed in the second one.

Comment: It is a public API, I don't have access to the server settings. Would the way that is set affect browsers differently?

Comment: Because the browser is going off the specification on one entry that is comma separated values.